# Undefined Reference to imp using mingw

Tags: c, eclipse, windows, gcc, undefined-reference

The problem I have is the "undefined reference to '_imp__...' " error that comes up when I build my project. I am using Windows 7, MinGW, Eclipse and .lib and .dll file that I did not make, but I took directly from the company that sold me their product.

I link with the -l command the HRDL.lib file and i have the PicoHRDL.dll at the same directory. The lib file is found (I'm sure about this), but the error comes up. I have included the complete path with the -L command. I have included the header file with the declarations of the functions, I get the undefined reference to, but the error is still there.

I have contacted both Eclipse support and Picotech support (the said company) but they weren't able to locate the problem till now.

These are the commands:

```
 gcc -O0 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o ACD_SOURCE.o "..\\ACD_SOURCE.c" 
 gcc "-LC:\\Users\\Falamana\\Desktop\\Eclipse\\ADC_project1\\Libraries" -shared -o libADC_24_DataLogger_App.exe ACD_SOURCE.o -lHRDL
```

These are the errors:

> ACD_SOURCE.o: In function `main':
>
> C:\Users\Falamana\Desktop\Eclipse\ADC_project1\Debug/../ACD_SOURCE.c:70:
>   undefined reference to `_imp__HRDLGetUnitInfo@16'
>
> C:\Users\Falamana\Desktop\Eclipse\ADC_project1\Debug/../ACD_SOURCE.c:99:
>   undefined reference to `_imp__HRDLCloseUnit@4'
>
> ACD_SOURCE.o: In function `SelectUnit':
>
> C:\Users\Falamana\Desktop\Eclipse\ADC_project1\Debug/../ACD_SOURCE.c:115:
>   undefined reference to `_imp__HRDLGetUnitInfo@16'
>
> C:\Users\Falamana\Desktop\Eclipse\ADC_project1\Debug/../ACD_SOURCE.c:167:
>   undefined reference to `_imp__HRDLGetUnitInfo@16'

Comment: Are you compiling a 64-bit build? The failed imports look like exports from a 32-bit binary (with `__stdcall` name decoration).

Comment: Thanks for this comment! it has helped a lot! 
so, i am building with 64bit libraries BUT, pico's example of the code said to build a 32bit application. my question is: to build a 32 bit app, do i need only the 64bit libraries or do i need anything else? for example, different functions (i'm using pico's function, as you can see at the original question). 
thanks again!

Comment: You cannot mix bitness. A 32-bit application requires 32-bit libraries, and a 64-bit application 64-bit libraries. You cannot compile a 32-bit application and link against a 64-bit library.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helpt to add `-mwindows` flag to linker options.

Answer (score -1):

Note that in your compiling information, the `-L` option symbol should be out of the quote. That's to say, the

```
gcc "-LC:\Users\Falamana\Desktop\Eclipse\ADC_project1\Libraries" -shared -o libADC_24_DataLogger_App.exe ACD_SOURCE.o -lHRDL
```

should be

```
gcc -L"C:\Users\Falamana\Desktop\Eclipse\ADC_project1\Libraries" -shared -o libADC_24_DataLogger_App.exe ACD_SOURCE.o -lHRDL
```

So please check your configuration of the lib directory in whatever IDE you are using, util the gcc line of compiling information looks normal( util `-L` stands right ahead of the quote character).

Comment: i tried changing it, but i cooulnt. but still, when i build the project, the commands seem to be working just fine, cause if i type "wrong" name of librarie an error comes up saing cannot find librarie, but when i type it correctly no error comes up. 
do i still need to find a way, or is it fine?